# ADB show permission error on Huawei Mate8

Tags: android, debugging, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I've tried everything I've read in blogs but not even activating logs help the same keeps appearing in ADB
C:\ADB>adb logcat -d -v time >.\log.txt
int logctl_get(): open '/dev/hwlog_switch' fail -1, 13. Permission denied

Note: log switch off, only log_main and log_events will have logs!

Need help desperately

Answer (score 0):

if you are debugging with your phone,

1. first try to activate Developer options in the phone settings.
2. enable the allow usb debugging options.
3. sync your device with android studio
4. Always "rebuild project" first before debugging